# Rails (Puma server) Phantomjs don't run on production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, phantomjs, ruby-on-rails-5, puma

I want to run PhantomJs on Controller.

in my file `test.js`

```
use 'strict';
console.log('HELLO WORLD');
```

in `my_controller.rb`

```
def test
  rs = `phantomjs 'path/to/test.js' `
  puts rs
end
```

When i run project on local in mode `development`,

- i go to action `/test` => it display `'HELLO WORLD'` ( work )

But when i deploy, and run it on mode `production`
It not display `HELLO WORLD`, seem like phantom js don't run.

I use Phantomjs 2.1.1, rails 5.1.5, ruby 2.3.5 and boot use Puma server.
Anyone can show me a way can fix it.

Comment: Are you using any gem for `Phantomjs`?? Check your GemFile

Comment: Also, recommend to move off of PhantomJS; it is not longer developed AFAIK. Try looking into Chrome headless, etc. Performs way better too.
https://hackernoon.com/benchmark-headless-chrome-vs-phantomjs-e7f44c6956c

Comment: Niraj KaushalL No, i don'i install gem for phantom js, I call phantomJs from cmd system

Answer (score 0):

try to make sure phantomjs is installed on your prod server, and the path setting is proper. run phantomjs  from your shell to verify this

Comment: when i run phantomjs from shell it work, But when run from controller in mode production (puma boot) it not work.

Comment: Are you running the puma thread under the same user with the current shell which phantomjs works?